# Framework for dynamically linking routes without stopping the core application

Tags: java

Now we are developing a system based on microservice architecture, which uses **messages** and Apache Kafka for **inter-service interactions**.
Messages will walk through core service according to **configured routes**.
Which involves configuring consumers, validators, transformers, splitters, routers, producers etc.
We know about Spring Intergration and Apache Camel.
But we want to implement **dynamically linked (hot plugged) routes without restarting the core service**.
Is there a **framework, tool, approach etc.** which implements such an idea?
Our development language is Java.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Most (Java) frameworks support wildcards in routes, which is what you need right?

E.g.

[Play](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.7.x/JavaRouting)

```
GET   /clients/:dynamicPart        controllers.Clients.show(dynamicPart: String)
```

[Spring](https://spring.io/guides/gs/serving-web-content/)

```
@GetMapping("/greeting")
public String greeting(@RequestParam(name="dynamicPart", required=false, defaultValue="World") String dynamicPart, Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("name", dynamicPart);
    return "greeting";
 }
```

Comment: Hi @Thomas! Thanks for your answer,

In my question, routes are understood as the way of processing and transfering messages **as part of interservice interaction, not REST**.
For example, in the context of how this is interpreted and used by **[Enterprise Integrational Patterns](https://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/patterns/messaging/MessagingComponentsIntro.html)**.